# bower install does not create folder with packages even though it is set up with .bowerrc (Mac)

Tags: macos, npm, frontend, bower

I am trying to set up an existing UI project on my mac machine using **npm** & **bower**. The project has proper `bower.json` and `.bowerrc` files. I run `npm install` followed by `bower install`. The expectation is that all the necessary bower packages will end up being created in the specified by `.bowerrc` directory. The `bower install` command seems to be executed with no errors, but the packages' folder is NOT created.

The contents of .bowerrc file:

```
{
    "directory": "libraries",
    "resolvers": [ "bower-npm-resolver" ]
}
```

The contents of bower.json file:

```
{
  "name": "ui-project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "license": "All rights reserved.",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.7.x",
    "angular-mocks": "~1.7.x",
    "angular-translate": "~2.17.x",
    "angular-translate-loader-static-files": "~2.17.x",
    "angular-animate": "~1.7.x",
    "angular-dynamic-locale": "~0.1.x",
    "angular-ui-router": "0.4.2",
    "angular-moment": "~1.1.0",
    "angular-i18n": "~1.7.x",
    "angular-ui-utils": "~0.1.1",
    "angular-messages": "~1.7.x",
    "angular-sanitize": "~1.7.x",
    "angular-uuids": "~0.0.4",
    "angular-cookies": "1.7.x",
    "animate.css": "~3.2.x",
    "restangular": "~1.5.0",
    "ngstorage": "~0.3.x",
    "moment": "~2.10.x",
    "ng-file-upload": "~2.2.x",
    "lodash": "~4.13.1",
    "file-saver": "1.3.3",
    "highcharts-release": "~4.1.x",
    "highcharts-pattern-fill": "https://github.com/highcharts/pattern-fill.git#3.0.2",
    "ng-focus-on": "~0.2.x",
    "ngSmoothScroll": "~2.0.0",
    "Sortable": "https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable.git#6952f3b525702e0daa9033b06e7e43e3a5c24692",
    "angulartics": "~1.6.0",
    "js-sha256": "~0.3.0",
    "angular-datepicker": "~2.0.3",
    "validator-js": "~8.2.0",
    "ip-address": "~5.8.8",
    "papaparse": "~4.3.7",
    "angulartics-piwik": "~1.0.6",
    "fusion-header": "npm:@muteam/fusion-header#2.1.53-light",
    "single-spa": "npm:single-spa#5.5.3",
    "single-spa-angularjs": "npm:single-spa-angularjs#3.3.0",
    "import-map-overrides": "npm:import-map-overrides#1.15.2",
    "zone.js": "npm:zone.js#0.10.3",
    "systemjs": "npm:systemjs#6.3.2"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "~1.7.x"
  }
}
```

The contents of package.json:

```
{
  "name": "ui-project",
  "version": "1.0.2361",
  "copyright": "All rights reserved.",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git@stash.muteam.com/ui-project.git"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=4.4.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "bower install",
    "postversion": "git add ./bower-lock.json && git commit --amend --no-edit",
    "test": "grunt test",
    "build": "grunt build",
    "grunt": "grunt",
    "grunt:dev": "grunt dev"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bower": "~1.8.8",
    "bower-npm-resolver": "^0.10.0",
    "chance": "^1.1.4",
    "connect-modrewrite": "^0.10.2",
    "my-custom-common-components": "^0.0.47",
    "grunt": "~0.4.5",
    "grunt-autoprefixer": "~1.0.1",
    "grunt-bower-task": "~0.4.0",
    "grunt-cli": "~1.2.0",
    "grunt-concurrent": "~2.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "~1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "~1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "~1.0.2",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "~1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~2.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-less": "~1.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~2.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^1.1.0",
    "grunt-exec": "^2.0.0",
    "grunt-git-describe": "~2.3.2",
    "grunt-html2js": "~0.3.6",
    "grunt-jsonlint": "~1.1.0",
    "grunt-karma": "~3.0.2",
    "grunt-less2js": "~0.1.5",
    "grunt-ng-annotate": "^2.0.2",
    "grunt-ng-constant": "~2.0.2",
    "grunt-ngdocs": "~0.2.11",
    "grunt-string-replace": "~1.2.1",
    "grunt-webfont": "~1.4.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "js-beautify": "1.6.14",
    "jshint-path-reporter": "~0.1.3",
    "karma": "~4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.2",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "~1.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^3.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-diff-reporter": "^0.6.2",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor": "~1.0.0",
    "less": "~1.7.3",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "~3.5.0",
    "lodash": "~4.13.1",
    "time-grunt": "~1.4.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "my-custom-framework": "^1.0.37"
  }
}
```

What could be wrong? Something with the user privileges?

Answer (score 1):

What is in your package.json and bower.json?

The syntax for `directory` looks right to me as far as comparing to another project of mine. Are you getting any errors after installation?

You might get more details if you try and `bower install --verbose`

Comment: I've updated my post with the details of package.json and bower.json. Unfortunately, I can't post the output of `bower install --verbose` here as it's too long, but I checked and everything looks fine there, no errors.

Answer (score 1):

Finally fixed the issue.  In my case, uninstalling brew's latest `node 14` and installing `node 12` from scratch through the regular installer helped.